# Как читать содержимое памяти?

Tags: отладка, ассемблер

**Здравствуйте!**

Что-то я туплю... В общем, как я могу прочитать байты, следующие за первыми четырьмя? [**Вот картинка, где все прекрасно видно**](http://snag.gy/D15f8.jpg), на которой все обозначено. Работаю в "Ольке". Понимаю, вопрос, возможно, глуп, но все же прошу Вашей помощи...

[image]

---

Ну и даже если, допустим, я понял, как читать данные из памяти. Теперь стало понятно, что по адресу `0x797000` хранятся наши 4 байтика (те, что в `EAX'`е ), значит в `0x797001` находится `0020(20)`, в `0x797002` - `041A`, в `0x797003` - `043E` и так далее.. Но, скажем, при попытке считывания этих байтов из памяти апишной функцией `ReadProcessMemory`, у меня ничего не выходит - читаются, только те "заветные" байты, что в еаксе:

```
void *lp = VirtualAllocEx(feed,(void*)0x401000,8,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
DWORD wc;
void *buff;
BOOL bl = ReadProcessMemory(feed,lp,&buff,8,&wc); /// 002E0022...
```

---

**Благодарю, друзья!**

Comment: Права на такую операцию есть(SeDebugPrivilege)? GetLastError() что вернул?

Comment: Права есть.